# Assign ng-model to checkbox if some value == anothervalue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a User object in Angular controller. I also have an array of Account objects with respective ID for each.

In User I have a field "default_account" where I want to put ID of a default account. So, user can have a lot of accounts but only one of them can be default. When I go to Account options, I have a checkbox there which is responsible for setting/unsetting the account as default.

Now I want to set checkbox on/off depending on its being default for the user. And I also need to respectively change default_account field inside User object on checkbox change. It puzzles me quite much how I can do it.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Hi Sergey, I've given you a working fiddle in my answer. Dewd

Comment: You might want to replace the checkbox with a radio button if only one account can be default account.

Answer (score 1):

Very approximate (didn't text that):

html:

```
       <div ng-repeat="account in accounts">
           <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="account == user.default_acount" 
                  ng-click="SelectAssDefault(account )" />
        </div>
```

js:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.user = { name: 'user', default_acount: null};
  $scope.accounts = [{  }, {  }, ...];

  $scope.SelectAssDefault = function (account) {
      $scope.user.default_acount = account;
  };
}
```

EDIT: a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ev62U/120/

Comment: `account == user.default_account` - `$scope.accounts` is an array of objects. The object will have many properties. What would be ideal here would be to simply store the account number in the user model and compare it with the account numbers existing. To make a comparison if the entire account information is the same is not needed. So the solution should be more of `account.account_number == user.default_acount` and not compare the entire account object (or even store the entire account object into the user model.

Comment: @callmekatootie, Okay, that's up to you to define the design and logic. The questions was not quite about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a checkbox to true based on a variable, you can set `ng-checked="variable"` within the input tag.

If the variable is `true` the box will be checked. If it's `false` it won't. Alternatively, an expression will also work e.g. `ng-checked="1===1"` will evaluate to true.

If you want to alter something else based on user clicking on the checkbox, set `ng-click="someCtrlFunction()"` within the input tag. This will call a function in your controller. You can look up the value of the checkbox from your controller if you've bound to it.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E8LBV/10/ and here's the code:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="account in user.accounts">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-checked="account == user.default" ng-click="changeDefault(user.id,account,checked)">{{account}}</input>
                </li>
                <ul/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
            var app = angular.module('App', []);

            app.service('Users', function () {
                var Users = {};

                Users.data = [{
                    'id': 1,
                        'name': 'jon',
                        'default': null
                }, {
                    'id': 2,
                        'name': 'pete',
                        'default': null
                }];

                return Users;

            });

            app.service('Accounts', function () {
                var Accounts = {};

                Accounts.data = [{
                    'user': 1,
                        'ac': 123456
                }, {
                    'user': 2,
                        'ac': 456832
                }, {
                    'user': 2,
                        'ac': 345632
                }, {
                    'user': 1,
                        'ac': 677456
                }];

                return Accounts;

            });

            app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, Users, Accounts) {
                $scope.users = Users.data;

                //attach accounts to user                
                for (i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
                    $scope.users[i].accounts = [];
                    for (ii = 0; ii < Accounts.data.length; ii++) {
                        if (Accounts.data[ii].user == $scope.users[i].id) {
                            $scope.users[i].accounts.push(Accounts.data[ii].ac);
                        }
                    }
                }

                    //function to change the default account for the user
                    $scope.changeDefault = function (id, account, checked) {
                        if (!checked) {
                            return;
                        }
                        for (i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
                            if ($scope.users[i].id == id) {
                                $scope.users[i].
                                default = account;
                            }
                        }
                    }    
            });
```

Comment: According to TS's request, I believe User and Account are different entities and Account itself should not know whether it's default.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that perfectly worked for me!

```
<tbody ng-repeat="account in accounts">
          <tr>
            <td ><a ng-click="getloandetails(account.idAccount)">{{account.accountName}}</a></td>
            <td>$ {{account.currentBalance}}</td>
          </tr>
</tbody>
```

and in Angular side just do this:

```
$scope.getloandetails = function(accountId) {
    alert('Gettring details for the accountId: ' + accountId);
};
```